# Dual Vector Space of linear functionals

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Am I correct in my understanding that given a basis $\left\{e_1,e_2,e_3\right\}$ for a vector space $V$, the corresponding basis elements $\left\{w_1,w_2,w_3\right\}$ of the dual space are orthogonal to the original basis? I.e., the plane $w_1$ is orthogonal to $e_1$, $w_2$ orthogonal to $e_2$, etc?
I'm still trying to wrap my mind around the dual space.
Thanks!

Comment: $w_1$, $w_2$, and $w_3$ are linear functionals on $V$ defined in a particular way. Their *null spaces* can be identified with planes, but they are not planes. At any rate, how are you defining orthogonal?

Comment: Hmm I guess I'm not conceptualizing what the dual space is so maybe I'll review other questions first and rephrase.  I was defining orthogonal as e1 dot w1 = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have in mind the duality pairing between elements (functionals) in the dual space $V^*$ and elements in the original space $V$. For $w\in V^*$ and $e\in V$ it is denoted by $\langle w,e\rangle_{V^*\times V}$ or if there is no danger of confusion which is the space and its dual, just $\langle w,e\rangle$. This notion looks like the notion for inner product $(.,.)$. If the original space $V$ is a Hilbert space, then using Riesz'reprezentation theorem, you can indeed write the action of the functional $w$ on the element $e$ using inner product: $\langle w,e\rangle=(Rw,e)=(z,e)$ where $R: V^*\to V$ is the Riesz izomorphism and $Rw$ is the image of $w$ in the space $V$. In this case the property of the basis that $\langle w_i,e_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$ can be transformd to orthogonality between the images of the $w_i,\,\,i=1,2,3,.. $ under the Riesz' izomorphism $R$ and the basis of $V$ $e_j, \,\,j=1,2,3,..$, i.e $\langle w_i,e_j\rangle =(Rw_i,e_j)=\delta_{ij}$

Answer (score 1):

The dual space $V^*$ of  vector space $V$ is the space of linear functionals on $V$, so it is a different space as $V$, so you can not define an inner product between tvo different spaces and you can not define the notion of orthogonality between elements of these different spaces.. And note that a basis in $V*$ is such that ( using your notation): $w_i(e_j)=\delta_{ij}$ so:
$$
w_1(e_1)=1 \qquad w_2(e_2)=1 \qquad w_3(e_3)=1
$$

Comment: Okay cool. What happens if we define an inner product between the two spaces?

Comment: I am not sure you can define such a thing.

Comment: I don't see how we can define such an ''inner product'' :)

Comment: Okay thanks!  I'll keep reading